# Bootstrap Multiselect - Single Checkbox with Options

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox, multi-select

Is it possible to build a Bootstrap Multiselect where the list functions like normal, BUT I have the ability to add a checkbox at the end?

I have a list I want to build where there are two versions of every option in the list. I would like the checkbox to serve as a toggle for the data.

**HTML:**

```
<select class="form-control" id="accompany">
     <option>None</option>
     <option>Metronome</option>
     <option>Piano</option>
     <option>Rock</option>
     <option>Pop</option>
     <option>Blues</option>
     <option>Latin</option>
     <option>Classical</option>
     <option><label><input type="checkbox" value="Melody">Melody</label></option>
</select>
```

**JS:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function() {
          $('#accompany').multiselect();
     });
</script>
```

I know this is not the proper syntax nor init values, but you can at least see what I'm *trying* to do from the HTML snippit

Comment: Do you want to add one more checkbox in addition to default checkbox rendered by multiselect plugin?

Comment: kinda-sorta. The options listed will function as radio buttons (only one can be selected) and the final to be the checkbox to toggle "Melody" on or off.

Comment: So you dont need a multiselect just normal select with ability to enable or disable the selection from dropdown list right? @Murphy

Comment: Can you post a fiddle?

Comment: dk_dragonknight - you are correct. It's a normal select form, but with a checkbox at the bottom to toggle different versions of the data. I thought that maybe the Bootstrap Multiselect plugin could do it. I have no fiddle, because I'm asking about functionality, and not coding errors.